# Cannot call member function without object (though I believe I did initialize it)

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to define my own sqrt func for my complex number class and call it in My_code namespace, which is brought about in the global main method.

When I try to compile and run the code, the

```
auto z2 = complex::sqrt(z);
```

doesn't go through the compiler.

I've tried printing my initialized complex number z, which works perfectly fine. I've also tried other functions like overloaded operators on z, and they also work fine. I am not sure where my problem lies.

```
//defining a new complex class and a function using your own namespace

#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace My_code{

class complex{

    double re, im;
public:
    complex(double r, double i): re(r), im(i) {}
    complex(double r): re(r), im(0) {}
    complex() : re(0), im(0) {}

    double real() const { return re; }
    double imag() const { return im; }

    complex& operator += (complex z){

        re += z.re;
        im += z.im;
        return *this;
    }

    complex& operator -= (complex z){
        re -= z.re;
        im -= z.im;
        return *this;
    }

    auto sqrt(const complex& number);
};

    auto complex::sqrt(const complex& number){

        auto re = number.real();
        auto im = number.imag();

        auto modulus = std::sqrt(re*re + im*im);
        auto x_sq = (re + modulus)/2;
        auto y_sq = modulus - x_sq;

        if(im < 0){
            //x & y are of opposite signs
            auto value = std::make_pair(complex(std::sqrt(x_sq), - std::sqrt(y_sq) ), complex(-std::sqrt(x_sq), std::sqrt(y_sq))); //tuple
            return value;}
        else{
            //x&y are of same signs
            auto value = std::make_pair(complex(std::sqrt(x_sq), std::sqrt(y_sq)), complex(-std::sqrt(x_sq), -std::sqrt(y_sq))); //tuple
            return value;}
    }

    int main();
}


int My_code:: main(){

    complex z {8, -6};
    auto z2 = complex::sqrt(z);
    //auto z3 = z2.first;
    //std::cout << '{' << z3.real() << ',' << z3.imag() << "}\n";
    std::cout << '{' << z.real() << ',' << z.imag() << "}\n";
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    My_code::main();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect my complex sqrt func to give me a pair of complex numbers that is (3, -1) & (-3, 1).

Comment: `sqrt` shouldn't take in a parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to go through"?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Oops it's "doesn't go through".

Comment: @DHH Right, but, what does that mean? What do you actually see? What actually happens?

Comment: It sounds like you want `sqrt` to be a `static` member. Though why not either make it a non-static member function with no argument, or even a free function?

Comment: If `z` is an instance of your class, then `z.sqrt()` is how you call the function on that instance. As others have said, you most likely do not want to pass it a parameter since you want to work on the actual instance. If you want to pass a parameter to get the square root of then you should make your `sqrt` function static and only use the parameter for your calculation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It would use `this` instead.

Comment: `sqrt` should either calculate the root of `this` or of its parameter, currently you have a mix of both. First decide for one and then either make it static or remove the parameter

Comment: @tkausl Oh, haha, this is his own `sqrt`. Okay :)

Comment: Note that the standard library provides [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) and it has `sqrt`.

Comment: Your main never examines or observes `z2`, and your code wouldn't compile, so I'm not really sure how we know which problem you're asking about here. Please present a [MCVE].

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I suppose that's what the OP means: It "doesn't go through"... the compiler.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Shame they didn't just tell us that then :(

Comment: One of the important lessons of programming is "Read the error message." In this case, "Cannot call member function without object" is telling you that you are calling an instance member function, but did not specify an instance. Instance member functions are typically called by saying `object.method()`. You wrote `classname::method()`, which is not a valid way to call an instance method, though it *is* a valid way to call a static method. At this point, you have to figure out how to reconcile the problem. Do you really want an instance method? Or do you want a static method?

Comment: Off-topic: I don't consider it useful to provide both roots as result (you always can get the other one easily by negating it) - it's just like returning -2.0 and 2.0 from std::sqrt(4.0). The only thing that might be less clear: which is the appropriate normalised variant? Always the one with positive real part (that's what [`std::sqrt(std::complex)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt) does)? The one having real the same sign as the original value's real? ...

Comment: Dear all, thx for great suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot call member function without object

Correct. You can only call non-static member functions using a member access operator. Member access operator requires an object as the left hand argument.

You can call your `sqrt` function like this for example:

```
complex z1 {8, -6};
complex z2 {8, -6};
auto z3 = z1.sqrt(z2);
```

That said, you never use members of the left hand argument, so it is unclear why you've declared the function to be a non-static member function. You may intended to declare a static member function instead. Static member functions can be called without member access operator, using exactly the syntax that you attempted to use with the non-static member function.

Comment: Thx. I got tunneled into the object init part, didnt realize it was an instance func.

Comment: Better make it a non-member function in this case so that you can take advantage of [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) when calling it.